# How can i get notified when someone else's google forms updates?

Tags: calendar, google-forms

I want to get my drivers license, in order to do that i need to plan a date on the website of the local driving license entity here. I saw that the website uses google forms to plan a date.
The thing is that the calendar is filled 'till december. They do regularly update their calendar but only when someone cancels their date.
So i got the idea that it would be fantastic if i could get a notification when the calendar updates.

Any guesses on how to do this?
Thanks!

I've tried to receive the calendar but go no succes since i dont really have much experience coding.
[photo of the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBUbZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**"How can i get notified when someone else's google forms updates?"**

Unless the calendar/form is shared with you, or you have other access to it or a linked spreadsheets, you can NOT receive notifications about another person's calendar/form.